# Can this be solved using a formula?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I've attempted this problem by drawing several possible paths from S to E given the above conditions - a process that is very tedious. I suspect that there is an easier way. Any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The goose has to go up exactly 3 units. So you can only have either 1 A + 1 C or 3 C, the rest has to be Bs. Can you take it from there? (Don't forget permutations)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other solutions show, it is easier to do this with a bit of forethought (and some combinatorics) rather than rely on a formula, but just in case you were truly looking for a direct formula, it can be done with generating functions.  The answer will be the coefficient of $x^3 y^3$ in the Maclaurin series expansion of

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1 - y^2 - x - xy}.$$

The exponents on $x$ and $y$ represent the relative displacements in the horizontal and vertical directions: $x^3 y^3$ represents the steps needed to get from S to E, $y^2$ represents move A, etc.

We can extract this coefficient mechanically by taking the mixed partial derivative $\partial^6 f \over \partial x^3 \partial y^3$,  evaluating at $(0,0)$, and dividing out by $36 = 3! \cdot 3!$ (which is the same mixed partial applied to $x^3 y^3$).  This single-line formula

$$\frac{1}{3!3!}\frac{\partial^6}{ \partial x^3 \partial y^3}\left(\frac{1}{1 - y^2 - x - xy} \right)\bigg|_{x=0,y=0}$$

ultimately yields 13, after a great amount of tedium to compute it :).

Comment: Many thanks, I will attempt this approach as well.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?  You may feel the original question is misguided, but of all the answers, this one answers the question most literally.  My point is largely that "using a formula" is possible, but having seen the actual formula, you might appreciate other non-formulaic approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider two cases.

i) The number of $A$ moves is $0$. Then there is only one way, that is $CCC$.

ii) The number of $A$ moves is $1$. Then, in some order, we use $A$, $C$, $B$ and $B$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

convert to algebra!  Let the coordinate of $S$ be $(0,0)$ and $E$ as $(3,3)$.

$A=(2,0)$, $B=(0,1)$, $C=(1,1)$.  Looking for $a,b,c$ where
$$
aA+bB+cC=(3,3)  \\
$$
which gives
$$
2a+c = 3 \\
b + c = 3
$$

$c$ should be odd.  Let $c=1$ solve for $a,b$; and again for $c=3$.
for $ a,b,c = 1,2,1$ you have $\frac{4!}{2!}$ permutations.  For $c=3$ there is only one.  Total 13.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to first write a $1$ in every square which can be reached from $S$. Then for each of those squares place a tally mark $2$ in each square you can reach on the second move. If there are two $2$s in a square you put two $3$s in each square you can reach from that square, because you can reach it on move $3$ in two ways (there may be other $3$s from other directions, and a square may contain a mixture of numbers). And similarly if there are more of the same number in a square.

Since all moves are up/left there will be no circuits, and all paths will eventually run off the edge. The numbers in square $E$ will tell you how many routes there are and also give you the distribution of route lengths in moves.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will try this approach.